# Why do I get errors about non-staic methods being referenced from the static context?

Tags: java

In the following block of code, I am trying to print the properties whose `location`, `monthlyRent`, `numberOfBedrooms` defined in the `Property` class being equal to this method's parameters in LettingAgent class. When I compiled, the error is occured in the if line where it says non-static method like `getlocation()` can't be referenced from static context.

```
/**
 * Java coursework on class property which present detail information about the property

public class Property
{
    // instance variables of class property.
    private String address;
    private char location;
    private double monthlyRent;
    private int numberOfBedrooms;
    private boolean occupied;
    private String tenantName;

    /** 
     * Constructor for object of class Property with required parameters. 
     */
    public Property( String addressinput, char locationinput, double Rentinput, int Bedsinput )
    { 
        //initialise the instance variables or fields of property class.
        address = addressinput;
        location = locationinput;
        monthlyRent = Rentinput;
        numberOfBedrooms = Bedsinput;
        occupied = false;
        tenantName = "";
    }

    /**
     * Return the address of the property
     */
    public String getAdress( )
    {
        return address;
    }

     /**
     * Return the location of the property
     */

    public char getLocation( )
    {
        return location;
    }

     /**
     * Return the monthlyRent of the property
     */
     public double getmonthlyRent( )
    {
        return monthlyRent;
    }

     /**
     * Return the numberOfBedrooms of the property
     */
     public int getnumberOfBedrooms( )
    {
        return numberOfBedrooms;
    }

     /**
     * Return the occupied value of the property
     */
     public boolean isoccupied( )
    {
        return occupied;
    }

     /**
     * Return the tenant's name of the property
     */
     public String gettenantName( )
    {
        return tenantName;
    }

     /**
     * Set the monthly rent to a new value
     */
     public void setmonthlyRent( double newRent )
    {
       monthlyRent = newRent;
    }

     /**
     * Adding tenant's name to the property
     */
     public void addtenantName(String newTenant)
    {
        if(occupied == false) {
            tenantName = newTenant;
            occupied = true; 
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(" The property is already occupied");
        }

    }

     /**
     * Removing tenant's name of the property
     */
     public void removetenantName( )
    {
        if( occupied == true) {
            tenantName = "";
            occupied = false;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(" The property is new and not occupied");
        }

    }

     /**
     * Print all the property attributes
     */
     public void printProperty( )
    {
        //simulate the printing of the property attributes.
       System.out.println( "The details of the property are as follow" );
       System.out.println("Address:" + address );
       switch(location){
           case 'n': case 'N': System.out.println("Location: North london" );break;
           case 's': case 'S': System.out.println("Location: South london" );break;
           case 'e': case 'E': System.out.println("Location: East london" );break;
           case 'w': case 'W': System.out.println("Location: West london" );
        } 

       System.out.println("Monthly-Rent:" + monthlyRent );
       System.out.println("Number of Bedrooms:" + numberOfBedrooms );
       System.out.println("Status of property:" + occupied );
       if(occupied == true) {
       System.out.println("Tenant Name:" + tenantName );
       }
       else {
           System.out.println("Property is empty at moment" );
        }

    }

}
```

**LettingAgent Class (calling class)**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Write a description of class LettingAgent here.
 */

public class LettingAgent
{
    // instance variables of LettingAgent Class.
    private ArrayList<Property>agproperty;
    private int Propnumber;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class LettingAgent
     */
    public LettingAgent()
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        agproperty = new ArrayList<Property>();
        Propnumber = 0;
    }

    /**
     * Return the property number of the Class LettingAgent. 
     */
    public int getPropnumber(){
        return Propnumber;
    }    

    /**
     *Method to add new property to the class LettingAgent via class Property.
     */
    public void addNewProperty(String addressinput, char locationinput, double Rentinput, int Bedsinput)
    {
        // put your code here
        Property newProperty = new Property(addressinput,locationinput,Rentinput,Bedsinput);
        agproperty.add(newProperty);

    }

    /**
     * @Description Method for removing the propety from the class LettingAgent.
     * @param int propnumber
     */
    public void removalOfProperty(int Propnumber)
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        if( Propnumber<agproperty.size()){
            agproperty.remove(Propnumber);
            System.out.println("The property has been removed");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("The Property number is not valid");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method for adding tenant to the property within class LettingAgent via class Property.
     */
    public void addTenant(int Propnumber, String newName, Property newProperty)
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        if( Propnumber<agproperty.size()){
            agproperty.get(Propnumber);
            newProperty.addtenantName(newName);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("The Property number is not valid");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method for removing tenant from the class LettingAgent via Property class.
     */
    public void removeTenant(int Propnumber,Property newProperty)
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        if( Propnumber<agproperty.size()){
            agproperty.get(Propnumber);
            newProperty.removetenantName( );

        }
        else{
            System.out.println("The Property number is not valid");
        }
    }

    /**
     *Method for searching property within the LettingAgent class.
     */
    public void searchProperty(String Address)
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        for(Property Property : agproperty){
            if (agproperty.get(Propnumber).equals( Address)){
                System.out.println("The details of the property is as follow"+ Property);
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("The property is not in the Letting agent's Stock");
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method for printing unoccupied property of the class LettingAgent.
     */

    public void printListOfUnoccupiedProperty( char Location, double maxmonthlyRent, int miniNoBeds)
    {
        // initialise instance variables
         for(Property property : agproperty){
        if((Property.getLocation().equals(Location))&&(Property.get(monthlyRent).equals(maxmonthlyRent))&&(agproperty.get(numberOfBedrooms).equals(miniNoBeds))){
            System.out.Println(Propnumber);
            Property.printProperty();
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("The Property number is not valid");
        }
    }
    }

}
```

Comment: -1 "Do some corrections"? Sorry, but this is a Q&A site, not a "please correct my code" site...

Comment: I voted to close as "not a real question" but I'll throw you some free advice:  The compiler is good at telling you which parts of your code are wrong enough to not even compile.  This code doesn't compile.

Comment: Actually I might be wrong...the many abuses of the Java naming conventions caused syntax highlighting that made things look like errors when they weren't.  `for(Property Property :...` I mean you.

Comment: Is `getLocation()` being called somewhere in your `main` method.  We really need to see all of the code to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: @Bill: this method is defined in my Property class source code which i have not posted here. Do you think its  would be alright if i post whole code of my Property class here. I feel like it would become long and messy.

Comment: @Dorji: Yes, please post it all, including the `main` method or unit test where your code is being called from.

Comment: Actually lettingAgent class is the class where i should include main method, but i don't need to write this method as i am developing in my Bluej IDE.

Comment: @Bill: i am so sorry for taking too much of your time.I feel like you have posted answer to my question but i am not getting how to view it. Hope you may tell me.

Comment: @Dorji: It's no trouble.  I just downloaded BlueJ and I'm compiling your new code now.  I'll post a new answer with what I find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the last method you define (formatted below):

```
/**
 * Method for printing unoccupied property of the class LettingAgent.
 */
public void printListOfUnoccupiedProperty(char Location, double maxmonthlyRent, int miniNoBeds) {
    // initialise instance variables
    for (Property Property : agproperty) {
        if ((Property.getLocation().equals(Location))
                && (Property.get(monthlyRent).equals(maxmonthlyRent))
                && (agproperty.get(numberOfBedrooms).equals(miniNoBeds))) {
            System.out.Println(Propnumber);
            Property.printProperty();
        } else {
            System.out.println("The Property number is not valid");
        }
    }
}
```

on the line:

```
&& (Property.get(monthlyRent).equals(maxmonthlyRent))
```

you're calling the `get` method of the `Property` variable.  I think that should be `Property.getMonthlyRent()`.

One other thing, in Java you should name your variables differently than their class names.  I would use something like

```
for (Property property : agproperty) { ...
```

I know it's a small change, but it makes a big difference in the readability of your code.  You can read about other Java code conventions in [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html).

Comment: In the following block of code, i am trying to print the properties whose location, monthlyRent, numberOfBedrooms defined in the Property class being equal to this method's parameter. for (Property Property : agproperty) {
        if ((Property.getLocation().equals(Location))
                && (P.get(monthlyRent).equals(maxmonthlyRent))
                && (agproperty.get(numberOfBedrooms).equals(miniNoBeds)))

Comment: @Dorji: Please edit the question and include all of your code and the error message you're getting from the compiler.

Comment: if ((Property.getLocation().equals(Location))
                && (P.get(monthlyRent).equals(maxmonthlyRent))
                && (agproperty.get(numberOfBedrooms).equals(miniNoBeds)))              In the above block of code, i am trying to print the properties whose location, monthlyRent, numberOfBedrooms defined in the Property class being equal to this method's parameters. When i compiled, the error is occured in this if line where it says non-static method like getlocation()can't be referenced from static context.

Comment: @Bill: sorry for the mess but i believe i have stated my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I've compiled your code in BlueJ now and this is what I've found.  First I get the error message

```
non-static method getLocation() cannot be referenced from a static context
```

When you changed the *variable* name from `Property` to `property` in the following line:

```
for(Property property : agproperty){
```

you needed to also change it where it is referenced in the next line:

```
if((Property.getLocation().equals(Location))&& ...
```

The word `Property` now only refers to the class name, so the phrase `Property.getLocation()` looks like a static method call.  You need to change that to:

```
if((property.getLocation().equals(Location))&& ...
```

Note the lower-case of `property`.

Next there are a few more method calls like `Property.get(monthlyRent)` that need to be fixed.  Again you'll need to change the variable name to `property` and put the correct method name in.

Following that I got the error message:

```
char cannot be dereferenced
```

This means that you're trying to call a method on a variable of the *primitive* `char` type.  You're doing that right at the beginning of the same method where you have:

```
property.getLocation().equals(Location) ...
```

You can't use the `equals` method on a `char` because it's a primitive type, not an Object type.  (What do you use instead to compare two primitives?)

You do the same thing again when you try to compare two `double` values.

```
property.getmonthlyRent().equals(maxmonthlyRent)
```

Next you have:

```
agproperty.get(numberOfBedrooms).equals(miniNoBeds)
```

Here the problem is a little bit more complicated.  It looks like you have the wrong variable name at the beginning of this phrase.  Think about what you want to compare here and look at the two previous problems you've fixed and I think you can figure out what should be here instead.

Comment: Thank you deeply for your patience in giving me a correct answer for my messy and long question being posted. I have used (==) to compare two primitive data types and it says no syntax errors. Thank You once again :)